# Convert to a Quadratic : $\frac{x^2}{0.00250-x}=4.2\cdot10^{-4}$

Tags: calculus

$\frac{x^2}{0.00250-x}=4.2\cdot10^{-4}$

I cant figure out how this equation was placed in this quadratic form:

$x^2+(4.2\cdot10^{-4})-(1.1\cdot10^{-6})=0$

Please show all steps?

Comment: Can't figure it out either, there is an $x$ missing.

Comment: There is no x missing. I assure you-

Answer (score 1, accepted):

hint: multiplying by $$0.00250-x$$ you will get
$$x^2=4.210^{-4}(0.00250-x)$$
can go further from here?
$${x}^{2}- 0.000001052500000+ 0.0004210000000\,x=0$$
multiplying outand now use the formula for the quadric equation

Comment: I still do not see it. If I multiply out the left side and subtract it I still have a mess.